# How to properly overload < operator in a struct to enable use in a set in C++

Tags: c++, struct, set, overloading

I am trying to create a set of struct in C++, an action requiring to overload the '<' operator.

Even though I did find a way to make it compile, it does not get encapsulated within the struct, therefore making it look unclean for OO design.

What I have tried which works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

struct Coordinate {
    int x, y;
};

bool operator<(const Coordinate& l, const Coordinate& r) {
    return l.x * l.y < r.x * r.y;
}

int main() {
    std::set<Coordinate> mySet;
    mySet.insert(Coordinate{ 5,5 });
}
```

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

struct Coordinate {
    int x, y;

    bool operator<(const Coordinate& other) {
        return this->x * this->y < other.x * other.y;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::set<Coordinate> mySet;
    mySet.insert(Coordinate{ 5,5 });
}
```

However the latter does not compile.

error message:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28508\include\xstddef(127,1): error C2678: binary '<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const _Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=Coordinate
1>        ]
1>C:\CppWorkspace\Dungeons of Doom\Dungeons of Doom\src\TestMain.cpp(7,7): message : could be 'bool Coordinate::operator <(const Coordinate &)'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28508\include\xstddef(127,1): message : while trying to match the argument list '(const _Ty, const _Ty)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=Coordinate
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28508\include\xstddef(126): message : while compiling class template member function 'bool std::less<Coordinate>::operator ()(const _Ty &,const _Ty &) const'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=Coordinate
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28508\include\xutility(1469): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool std::less<Coordinate>::operator ()(const _Ty &,const _Ty &) const' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=Coordinate
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28508\include\xmemory(1318): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::less<Coordinate>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28508\include\xmemory(1318): message : see reference to variable template 'const bool is_empty_v<std::less<Coordinate> >' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28508\include\set(54): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree<std::_Tset_traits<_Kty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=Coordinate,
1>            _Pr=std::less<Coordinate>,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<Coordinate>
1>        ]
1>C:\CppWorkspace\Dungeons of Doom\Dungeons of Doom\src\TestMain.cpp(17): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::set<Coordinate,std::less<Coordinate>,std::allocator<Coordinate>>' being compiled
```

I am new to C++ and was wondering whether there is a way to do something like this.

Comment: What compilation error do you get when you try to use the member method?

Comment: @JohnFilleau Oh yes I forgot to add that in as it was a long error message (coming from templates) I will edit the question and add it in

Comment: Re: " it does not get encapsulated" -- encapsulation is overrated. The code in the first example in the question is just fine.

Comment: re: encapsulation. This would all be encapsulated in one or two files, `Coordinate.h` & `Coordinate.cpp`. That's enough encapsulation for me.

Comment: @vasiliscsc I know you've accepted an answer already, but take a look at my answer too since your `operator<` has a big flaw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look at the compile error?

As it says, the method needs to be const

```
bool operator<(const Coordinate& other)  const {   // const the < operator
        return this->x * this->y < other.x * other.y;
    }
```

Comment: Reading the error message is what got me to the solution I mentioned, but it was a solution I did not like. Thanks for your input! This one works like I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

`operator<` needs to be `const`, but a bigger problem is that the operator doesn't do proper [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering) that's mentioned in the [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) named requirement.

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

struct Coordinate {
    int x, y;
    Coordinate(int X, int Y) : x(X), y(Y) {}

    bool operator<(const Coordinate& other) const {
        return this->x * this->y < other.x * other.y;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::set<Coordinate> mySet;
    mySet.emplace(1, 5);
    mySet.emplace(5, 1);
    std::cout << mySet.size() << '\n';
}
```

This will output `1` since the second `Coordinate` will be considered equal to the first when using that `operator<`.

A proper version could look like this:

```
    bool operator<(const Coordinate& other) const {
        return x==other.x ? y < other.y : x < other.x;
    }
```

Or better, use [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) from `<tuple>` which simplifies this considerably:

```
    bool operator<(const Coordinate& other) const {
        return std::tie(x, y) < std::tie(other.x, other.y);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this. I was aware that the current "implementation" of Coordinate would result in that problem. I just used this code as a simple example to demonstrate the problem of my question, it is not my actual code. However you did teach me std::tie with this which is awesome! Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

It's better that the comparison operators be friend functions.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

struct Coordinate {
    int x, y;

    friend bool operator<(const Coordinate& lhs, const Coordinate& rhs) {
        return lhs.x * lhs.y < rhs.x * rhs.y;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::set<Coordinate> mySet;
    mySet.insert(Coordinate{ 5,5 });
}
```

Comment: Marking this function "friend" makes no difference here. The data members are public, so there's no need for privileged access.

Comment: True. I would have just left it at the first snippet of code. But they wanted it in the struct The bigger idea is that the better practice is for comparative operators to not be member functions. And if you want it in the struct, but not a member function, you pick friend. And I think that answers the headline question of how to *properly* overload `operator<`.